# How exactly Hex editor is used?

Tags: binary-analysis, decryption, unpacking

I'm new to reverse engineering. So I decided to start with some game files in my computer. The main goal was to understand how hex editor used to identify files and extract needed data.

In my case I have 2 `.ebx` files and Chunk ID file. The goal is to use the `ebx` to extract the data in the chunk file but I am confused. I used 010 editor template to see whether it will find any wav/mp3 data, and it did. I appreciate if someone can explain some of the stuff here and give me some good tuts where I can learn this kind reversal?

[Chunk ID file](https://mega.nz/file/rkJWhTpB#c0v5bJfcsriYhK18TcAJZd9Uj4KQiae8u_R2y5ziyUs)

[Ebx File audio](https://mega.nz/file/LspmCKjJ#iTHgpTS0TDteXZGwKVjEeDiFPdvj0HlEKTa2oXARznU)